# All images are broken in help system

Tags: intellij-idea

I have not existent images in Intellij Idea 13 help system. Running on new .IntelliJIdea13 folder not solved it, I watched in log too. Any ideas, plase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the 13.0.1 release (build #133.331). You have a few options:

1. Revert to the 13.0 release.
2. [Download the 13.0.2 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP) (Early Access Program) build and use it. The issue has been fixed in it.
3. Replace the `<idea-install-dir>/help/ideahelp.jar` file in your 13.0.1 install directory with one from a previous 13.0 install, or the one from the 13.0.2 EAP ZIP file.
4. Wait for the official 13.0.2 release.

**EDIT**

There is a bug in the code formatter in the latest 13.0.2 EAP release (build 133.471), so you may want to forgo option #2